# Adding string functionality to codemirror define mode function

Tags: javascript, codemirror, codemirror-modes

I am making a editor for js but with additional keywords and other things. But the only problem is that I am unable to add string functionality to it.

```
'' and "" don't have any color
```

Can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

Check C-Like ..

https://codemirror.net/mode/clike/ it supports all coding languages that looks like C... including Java and C#.

All of these languages have color for string variables.